# Error while compiling a C program in a web page

Tags: php, c, gcc

I have got this error when i tried to compile a c program. "'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."  I have done all the coding in php. Please help me out.

Comment: It appears `gcc` is not installed or not in your path. Ensure that gcc is installed and use `which gcc` to get the path of gcc and use full path (less recommended) or ensure the path is added in list of locations where binaries are present. (Are you using chroot?)

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of the error, you are running your program on a windows PC. Follow this guide to set up gcc on your machine.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3w0igwp-FM